# Is there a 'local' version of Near Coherence of Filters?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, order-theory, ultrafilters, stone-cech-compactification

The axiom Near Coherence of Filters (NCF) is known to be independent of ZFC.

> **Axiom** (NCF I): For any two free ultrafilters $\mathcal D$ and $\mathcal E$ on $\mathbb N$, there exist finite-to-one functions $f,g: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $f(\mathcal D) = g(\mathcal E)$.

Where we define $f(\mathcal D) = \{A \subset \omega: f^{-1}(A) \in \mathcal D\}$. Equivalently $f(\mathcal D)$ is the unique ultrafilter generated by $\{f(D): D \in \mathcal D\}$

There is an equivalent version of the axiom.

> **Axiom** (NCF II): For any two free ultrafilters $\mathcal D$ and $\mathcal E$ on $\mathbb N$, there exists a finite-to-one monotone function $f :\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $f(\mathcal D) = f(\mathcal E)$.

One can ask if the same property holds over an upper-subset of $\mathbb N^*$: First define the preorder $\le$ on $\mathbb N^*$ where $\mathcal F \le \mathcal D$ means that $\mathcal F = f(\mathcal D)$ for some finite-to-one monotone function $f :\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$. Now fix some $\mathcal F \in \mathbb N^*$ and define $(\mathcal F \uparrow) = \{ \mathcal D \in \mathbb N^*: \mathcal F < \mathcal D \}$

Is anything known about the following proposition?

> **Axiom?:** For any two free ultrafilters $\mathcal D, \mathcal E \in (\mathcal F \uparrow)$, there exists a finite-to-one monotone function $f :\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $f(\mathcal D) = f(\mathcal E) \in (\mathcal F \uparrow)$.

In particular:

1. Is the proposition consistent?
2. Does it follow from any well-known additional axioms?
3. Does it hold for any known $\mathcal F$ under ZFC?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this is standard notation, but what do you mean by $f(\mathcal{D})$?  Do you mean the set of inverse images of elements of $\mathcal{D}$ under $f$, or the set of forward images?

Comment: The collection of sets whose inverse image is in $\mathcal D$. Equivalently the ultrafilter generated by all the the forward images.

Comment: If the filter $\mathcal F$ is meager, then your Axiom seems to be  equivalent to NCF. If $\mathcal F$ is not meager, then everything depends on the choice of $\mathcal F$. For example your Axiom trivially holds if $\mathcal F$ is an ultrafilter. So, maybe you want to ask if NCF is equivalent to your Axiom for any non-meager filter $\mathcal F$?

Comment: @Daron Observe that non-meager filters for their existence need some strong form of Axiom of Choce. All definable filters (for example, analytic or coanalytic) are meager.

Comment: Sorry, there was a mistake in the definition of the preorder. The two elements should have been the other way around. I see how this makes the axiom trivial for $\mathcal F$ an ultrafilter (we assume everything is an ultrafilter). I have corrected the mistake now. Is the axiom still trivial?

Comment: @Daron It seems that you axiom is alwas true: given two finite-to one maps $f,g$ with $f(\mathcal D)=\mathcal F=g(\mathcal D)$, you should produce one map $h$ witnessing that $h(\mathcal D)=h(\mathcal E)$. The technique for producing such a map $h$ is standard and can be found in the papers of Blass or Mildenberger. If you want, I can write details as an answer to your problem.

Comment: I believe that if $f(\mathcal D) = \mathcal F = g(\mathcal E)$ we can always construct a finite-to-one monotone $h$ such that $h(\mathcal D) = h (\mathcal E) = \mathcal F$, and that is the reason the axioms NCFI and NCFII are equivalent. But in order for the new axiom to hold we must also be able to demand $h(\mathcal D) = h (\mathcal E) > \mathcal F$ which does not happen if $h(\mathcal D) = h (\mathcal E) = \mathcal F$. Can the standard technique be modified to make that happen?

Comment: @Daron This $h$ (in the argument I know) does not have the property $h(\mathcal D)=h(\mathcal E)=\mathcal F$. The filter $h(\mathcal D)=h(\mathcal E)$ is below $\mathcal F$ in you order (which is called the Rudin-Blass order). I think that Andreas Blass should know much more on this topic.

Comment: I get what you are saying. I agree that if the proposed axiom was. . .

Comment: For any two free ultrafilters $\mathcal D, \mathcal E \in (\mathcal F \uparrow)$, there exists a finite-to-one monotone function $f :\mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ such that $f(\mathcal D) = f(\mathcal E)$

Comment: Then it would be trivial from what you have said. But the requirement that $f(\mathcal D), f(\mathcal E) > \mathcal F$ makes things harder.